# I'm small of eye and large of ear

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

I strike out at many a sphere

I sing a song you'll never hear

I fill many fragile hearts with fear

I'm small of eye and large of ear

What am I?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you may be a

> bat

I strike out at many a sphere

> Bats are used for many ball games like cricket and tennis

I sing a song you'll never hear

> Bats make calls to echolocate at a frequency too high for humans to hear naturally

I fill many fragile hearts with fear

> Fear of bats is [chiroptophobia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear_of_bats).  Thanks to Mike Limburg for this!

I'm small of eye and large of ear

> Bats - the flying mammals - have small eyes and large ears

Comment: Ahh Tom, you were just a minute ahead of me ;)

Answer (score 8):

This is probably a long shot and incorrect, but I'm thinking

> A large radio telescope observatory, like [Arecibo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arecibo_Observatory)

I strike out at many a sphere

> Broadcasting messages to stars and planets in hopes of extraterrestrial contact

I sing a song you'll never hear

> Broadcasts are inaudible to the human ear

I fill many fragile hearts with fear

> Conspiracy theorists? Or people wary of extraterrestrial life in general

I'm small of eye and large of ear

> Small observatory, but large listening array which can 'hear' a very large range of signals from space.

Comment: Nope.  Not even close.  Love it though.  +1

Answer (score 8):

Are you...

> A bat?

I strike out at many a sphere

> Striking out is a term in baseball, using "a bat" to hit the ball;

I sing a song you'll never hear

> We humans do not see you very often, so we will never hear you sing (can you even sing?);

I fill many fragile hearts with fear

> There is actually a fear for you: [chiroptophobia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear_of_bats).

I'm small of eye and large of ear

> Literally small-eyed and large-eared

Comment: Yep.  Good explanations too.  Tom just beat you to it though.

Comment: I like the chiroptophobia explanation!

Comment: Thanks Mike for this - I added your precise description (to mine)!.

Comment: You're more than welcome ;)

Answer (score 5):

You are

> Corn

I strike out at many a sphere

> Consumption of High Fructose Corn Syrup is linked to testicular cancer which afflicts the balls (spheres)

I sing a song you'll never hear

> As the corn grows, it makes a noise that is too inaudible for the human ear to detect

I fill many fragile hearts with fear

> A diet high in high fructose corn syrup causes obesity, diabetes, and heart failure.

I'm small of eye and large of ear

> Corn is known to come in ears and is the only crop that hosts *eye spot*, a disease that causes small eye-like dots on the leaves.

Comment: Lol I love this take on it

Comment: This answer is a dangerous mix of randomocity and devious, cleverness.  Big shiny +1 for you.